# How to get the value of AttributeName of XMLAttribute of object C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

I want to use reflection to get the AttributeName of an XMLAttribute.

```
public class Rate{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "roomcode")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

When I do:

```
var rate = typeof(Rate).GetProperty("Code").GetCustomAttributes(true);
```

I can see that there is a property on the object rate with AttributeName "roomcode", but no matter what I try, I can't seem to access it.

[image]

I want to do a unit test where I compare the attributenames on my object to the attributenames of an xml node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetCustomAttributes` returns an `object[]`, so you need to cast to `XmlAttributeAttribute` to access the `AttributeName` property.

One way would be to use LINQ `Cast` and `Single`:

```
var rate = typeof(Rate)
    .GetProperty("Code")
    .GetCustomAttributes(true)
    .Cast<XmlAttributeAttribute>()
    .Single()
    .AttributeName;
```

But it would be more concise to use the [`GetCustomAttribute<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute?view=net-5.0#System_Reflection_CustomAttributeExtensions_GetCustomAttribute__1_System_Reflection_MemberInfo_System_Boolean_) extension method, which obtains a single attribute of the given type `T`:

```
var rate = typeof(Rate)
    .GetProperty("Code")
    .GetCustomAttribute<XmlAttributeAttribute>(true)
    .AttributeName;
```

---

As an aside, you could also use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) when obtaining the `PropertyInfo` to improve type safety:

```
var rate = typeof(Rate)
    .GetProperty(nameof(Rate.Code))
    .GetCustomAttribute<XmlAttributeAttribute>(true)
    .AttributeName;
```

Comment: The moment you answered it, I found it. Thanks for your answer and the tip for using nameof!